# At what gravity would the rocket equation mean "cannot reach orbit from the surface"?

Tags: escape-velocity, rocket-equation

I remember reading (a long time ago in a library far, far away...) that, if Earth's gravity were *that* much stronger, the rocket equation (?) would mean that it were impossible to actually reach orbit from the surface given contemporary (chemical) propulsion.

I cannot for the life of me remember *where* I read it, or the exact numbers.

This came up again recently in a discussion on [worldbuilding.SE](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/104595/2340). Can anyone give me a rough estimate of **how strong a gravitational field could no longer be "escaped" to orbit given chemical propellants**, making space exploration effectively impossible for the theoretical inhabitants of such a stellar body?

Comment: Note that "no orbit possible" is different from "can't reach orbit from the surface".

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: Good point, clarified that a bit.

Comment: I (obviously) think this is a really interesting question. The answers and comments there show how well this site works when people work together to "get to the bottom" of a question, but finally @RussellBorogove 's answer puts reality to the exponential nature of the results of the [Tyranny of the Rocket Equation](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html) as explained by astronaut Don Pettit.